# EJS- Change page content and URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, express, ejs

I want the content of a page to change when a link in the sidebar is being clicked and also the url should change without the sidebar reloading.
I have been able to achieve changing the main content of the page without reloading the sidebar but I also need to change the url and make it specific to what sidebar content is being clicked.

**How I change the content**

***HTML*** - When you click *Welcome* or *Creating account* it calls the `changeContent()` function

```
 <div class=" sidebar-item sidebar-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="header-menu">
                            <span>Get Started</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="changeContent('/docs')"> <span id="welcome-btn" class="menu-text">Welcome</span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
                            <a> <span class="menu-text">Setting up</span> 
                            </a>
                            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li> <a id="creating-account" onclick="changeContent('/docs/settingUp')">
                                            Creating account</a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Starting transactions</a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Resolving transactions</a> </li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Refund</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
</div>
  <!-- page-content  -->
        <div class="main--c">
        <%- include ../partials/docs/welcomeDocs.ejs %>
        </div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
  function changeContent(url) {
        $('.main--c').load(url);
    }
```

My express config

```
router.get('/docs', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('pages/docs');
})
router.get('/docs/settingUp', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('partials/docs/settingUp');
})
```

This works, it changes the content without reloading the whole page but when you click on *Create account* I want to also change the url. So that whenever someone enters the url in the browser, It should load the *create account* page.

I tried add `href="docs/settingUp"` to the anchor tag but instead it loads only the partial page without the navbar and other styling

Comment: A article i found out: https://computerrock.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: The method worked, but if I go to `http://localhost:8080/docs/settingUpCraw` directly from my browser it loads just the partial file alone without the sidebar.